# counter ID number instead of random ID number?

Tags: php

Good day,
I have a problem and i dont know how to do a Counting id number instead of random numbers, please help me. Thank you.
My codes working on random id, but i want it in Counting number ID. Thanks

```html
<?php
    $hostname_conn = "localhost";
    $database_conn = "user_id";
    $username_conn = "root";
    $password_conn = "";
     $conn = mysql_pconnect($hostname_conn, $username_conn,   $password_conn) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
   mysql_select_db($database_conn,$conn);
   // run an endless loop      
    
    while(1) {       
    
    $randomNumber = mt_rand(10, 100);// generate unique random number               
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tblrand WHERE the_number='".mysql_real_escape_string ($randomNumber)."'";  // check if it exists in database   
    $res =mysql_query($query,$conn);       
    $rowCount = mysql_num_rows($res);
    $id=$randomNumber;
     // if not found in the db (it is unique), then insert the unique number into data_base and break out of the loop
    if($rowCount < 1) {
    $con = mysql_connect ("localhost","root");      
    mysql_select_db("user_id", $con);       
    $sql = "insert into tblrand(the_number) values('".$randomNumber."')";      
    mysql_query ($sql,$con);        
    mysql_close ($con);
    break;
    }   
}
  echo "IT-FORM" .$id;
   ?>
```

Comment: Maybe you just need an `auto_increment` field in your table (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Answer (score 0):

**CASE 1:** id generated by server-side

At server side, configure mysql database to generate sequential unique id. Add a field in your
table with auto-increment
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html as suggested by
@Londeren

Client side just manage insert query to save data in database (not ids, just data related to ids).

Generally this solution is preferable: even if you have many clients, the database will manage all
the query methodically and efficiently.

**CASE 2:** id generated by client-side (not preferable, use CASE 1 if possible. Included this in
the answer because your question started from here)

You get the last id from database, generate a new one (last id + 1), and insert new id in the
database.

Client side manage select id query, generate new id, and insert query. You take the
risk that other clients generate the same id simultaneously and insert it in the database.

Supposing at server-side is everything ok, code at client-side could be this:

```
<?php
$hostname_conn = "localhost";
$database_conn = "user_id";
$username_conn = "root";
$password_conn = "";
$conn = mysql_pconnect($hostname_conn, $username_conn, $password_conn) or
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
mysql_select_db($database_conn,$conn);
// run an endless loop
$count=1;
while(1) {
$query = "SELECT * FROM tblrand WHERE the_number='".mysql_real_escape_string
($count)."'"; // check if it exists in database
$res =mysql_query($query,$conn);
$rowCount = mysql_num_rows($res);
// if not found in the db (it is unique), then insert the unique number into data_base and break
out of the loop
if($rowCount < 1) {
$con = mysql_connect ("localhost","root");
mysql_select_db("user_id", $con);
$sql = "insert into tblrand(the_number) values('".$count."')";
mysql_query ($sql,$con);
mysql_close ($con);
$count++;
break;
}
}
echo "IT-FORM" .$count;
?>
```